# Unable to see notification on Android phone

Tags: beacon, eddystone, eddystone-url

I can see notifications within the Nearby app, but they do not show up within my Notifications bar.

I have "Nearby links available turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a detailed post on how to troubleshoot Eddystone notifications on Android:
https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/troubleshooting-eddystone-url-on-android/